# Can you install two different versions of Android Studio on the same machine?

Tags: android, android-studio

I only have one machine (Mac OS 10.9.5).  I currently have the canary version of Android Studio and I ran into some bug.  So I want to install the stable version of Android Studio as well.  Has anyone done that?  Is there any issue with more than one version installed on the same machine?

Comment: Yes, Its possible. Refer the following link. [https://developer.android.com/studio/preview/install-preview.html](https://developer.android.com/studio/preview/install-preview.html)

Comment: For Mac OS go to Application-->Rename Android Studio App to some thing else like Android Studio V1.0 and then install new one.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, but you have to alter the settings of one of the installations to point it to a different settings and cache folders.
After an install, but before the first run, change the location of those folders according to [this document](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/entries/23348963).

Comment: Alas, the link is not valid anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to list this as an OSX question. Since I'm not currently on my Mac I can't confirm, but it wouldn't hurt to download it and see.  You'd be ask to confirm any installation before it happens.  A lot of Max .dmg files can run the application in a self contained container without ever installing it.  If it launches a GUI that has you drag the Software over to the App folder you can sometimes just launch the app as is.  If it has to install it you could always move the existing Android Studio to another location and name and then install the new one (This would require looking up on OSX how to do that)

Answer (score 0):

In general, you can.

But beware that there are cache folders under `~/Library/ApplicationSupport/AndroidStudioBeta` (or `~/Library/ApplicationSupport/AndroidStudioPreview` for the real old versions) and `~/Library/Caches/AndroidStudioBeta` that will be shared between all "installations". So if your bug is related to something inside that folder (e.g a plugin) then you'll have a problem ;-)

You shouldn't use both versions at the same time, though.